# Admob Not enough space to show ad with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, admob, android-constraintlayout

I just changed my activity into fragment but now my ads no longer show because:

> W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 344x496 dp.

I do not understand why it tells me not enough space whereas if I set the values myself (what I do not want to do) this working and ad is displayed on just over half.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Score.FragmentScore"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableau"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:stretchColumns="*" />
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can u place the adview outside the constraintlayout

Comment: Is your fragment wider enough to hold the Ad? .Try changing the Ad width from `match_parent` to `360dp`

Answer (score 1):

Since the ScrollView is constrained to the adView, the adView must be placed before the scrollView.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Score.FragmentScore"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableau"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:stretchColumns="*" />
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your parent layout. Based from your logs, "Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 344x496 dp". You are missing 16dp you might have assigned some margin somewhere in your layout.

I cannot see any margins set in the layout that you pasted so I assume that you are adding your fragment to another layout. Check if it has any margins. ConstraintLayout sometimes set margins to added views. Here is an example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_toolbar"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You will have to change the margins to 0dp so that your code will work.